# how to detect mouse events in win32 api?

Tags: winapi, mouse, mouseevent

I would like to detect mouse events like left button click, right button click etc in win32. Is it possible to detect these events anywhere on the screen, not just over the window?

From my search i found setCapture() function but it requires a handle to the window, and i do not want to use a window.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must try using a wide system [hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to detect the mouse activity. check the [`WH_MOUSE_LL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#wh_mouse_llhook) and the [`WH_MOUSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#wh_mousehook) hooks.

Comment: Is system wide the only way? I wanted to monitor and in certain cases prevent dispatching/bubbling of mouse events, but just for my applicaiton, is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Use winapi GetKeyState function
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Parameter:
1 - left mouse click, 2 - right mouse click, etc